# EditText Android Studio keyboard

Tags: android

I have a problem: I click in the EdditText but the keyboard doesn't appear. I don't know how can I do to resolve the problem:

```
    et_num.setText (et_num.getText());

        et_num.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                et_num= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_num);
                et_num.requestFocus();
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.showSoftInput(et_num, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
                //InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);

              return false;
            };

        });
```

Comment: Usually you don't need a custom touch listener to make keyboard appear, could you provide more information about your use case?

Comment: Are you using an emulator? If the emulator is configured to have a physical keyboard (e.g. you computer keyboard) it will not show the soft keyboard on screen.

Comment: Egor: I tasted this app on a android mobile and the soft keyboard didn't apperard. Sorry with the speling misteakes

Comment: @Egor I tasted this app on a Android mobile and the soft keyboard didn't appear. Sorry with the spelling mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be an issue of focus on your EditText. Just add `<RequestFocus />` after the EditText in your app xml layout file.

Example:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/et_num"
    android:hint="0"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:focusable="true" />
    <requestFocus />
```

Also as @cyroxis said, If you're using a emulator with a keyboard you must configure the settings of the device to use the soft, in an Api 23 custom phone just tabbing twice at the screen will show you an icon, just touch and will appear the soft keyboard.

Also you can make a public method to hide the keyboard on lose focus.

```
public void hide_board()
{
    InputMethodManager im=(InputMethodManager)this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    im.hideSoftInputFromWindow(b_calcula.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

to make your keyboard visible

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```

or else you can set in manifest also

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"
```